# Extracting the matching element from a tuple inside a list

Tags: list, erlang, tuples, matching

Title says it all so I basically pass a list to my function let's say,
L = [{"Socrates", "fork1,fork2"},{"Confucius","fork2,fork3"},{"Aristole", "fork3,fork4"}, {"Homer","fork4,fork5"},{"Plato","fork5,fork1"}]

I pass the value to be matched and this list but when I find the matching value i want to pass ONLY the second element of a list so for example if I pass "Socrates" I should get back "fork1,fork2"

here are my two functions involved with that

```
whichFork({Name},[X|Xs])  ->
 Fork  = element(2,X),%get forks 
 Phil  = element(1,X),%get phil name
 Check = are_the_same(Phil,Name),%find out if they match 
  case Check of
    true-> Fork;%return forks in string
    false->whichFork(Name,Xs)%false repeat iterating the list
  end;
whichFork(_,[]) ->  %not found
false.

are_the_same(A,B) when A=:=B ->
  true;
are_the_same(_,_) ->
  false.
```

I searched over the site and no questions like that exists so any help much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can use `proplists:get_value`.
Here is the doc:
http://erlang.org/doc/man/proplists.html#get_value-2

```
1> L = [{"Socrates", "fork1,fork2"},{"Confucius","fork2,fork3"},{"Aristole", "fork3,fork4"}, {"Homer","fork4,fork5"},{"Plato","fork5,fork1"}].
4> proplists:get_value("Socrates", L).
"fork1,fork2"
```

if you want the  total element, maybe you can use http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#keyfind-3

Answer (score 1):

BlackMamba already gave you an answer, but I have 2 remarks on your code.

First regarding error management, in the philosopher problem there is no chance (except a bug in your code) that you are looking for a name that doesn't exist, so the case `whichFork(_,[]) -> false.` is useless and simply delay the moment when your code will crash.

Second is the usage of pattern matching: you can write the code `are_the_same(A,B) when A=:=B -> ...` this way `are_the_same(A,A) -> ...` it gives the same result, and you can extend this to the wichFork function:

```
whichFork(Name,[{Name,Forks}|Xs])  -> Forks;
whichFork(Name,[_|Xs])  -> whichFork(Name,Xs).
```